# How can I run OrientDB without Snappy?

Tags: orientdb, snappy

We are using OrientDB in its embedded Java mode (not as a separate server process), and would like to avoid having Snappy executed from `/tmp` (for security reasons).

My understanding is that Snappy is for compression. I have found a couple references to disabling compression in the XML config file for an OrientDB server, but that doesn't apply to us. Glancing through the source code, it looked like there might be an `ALTER` command that might change the compression setting, but a) I couldn't see what that command would be, and b) running it at that point might be too late, as snappy might already have been loaded.

The other option would be if we could just install the `snappy.so` library permanently on the server, and have OrientDB use that copy. I suspect that's not possible, but figured I would mention it in case it is.

We are using OrientDB 1.7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the JVM with this option:

```
-Dstorage.compressionMethod=nothing
```

The important is to create the database with such mode. Before 2.0 (still in snapshot status now) you have to create and use the database with such setting.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up calling System.setProperty instead, but it works great.